# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index x , length 0 without a loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexoutofboundsexception, stringbuilder

i'm currently adding functionality and completing a Hang-Man game my programing teacher made.

The following error message: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index 0, length 0 with the index changing for everyindex in a String builder. is appearing everytime i input a letter that is correctly guessed in the game.

I have tried for a while to fix it but i have yet to be able to.

```
package hangManSo;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class HangManSO extends JPanel implements             ActionListener, MouseListener {
private int error;
JButton button;
JTextField field;
JFrame frame;
JLabel rättord;

HangManSO(JButton button, JTextField field, JFrame frame, JLabel rättord) {
    this.button = button;
    this.field = field;
    this.frame = frame;
    this.rättord = rättord;
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}

static String [] ord = {"rome"}; 
static Random r = new Random();
static int randomNumber=r.nextInt(ord.length);
static String d = ord[randomNumber];

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(d.length());
StringBuilder builderDisplay = new StringBuilder();

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    
    String guessedletter = field.getText();
    
    if (source.equals(button)) {
        
         
        if (!d.contains(guessedletter)) {
            error++;
            frame.repaint();
        }
        
        
        if (d.contains(guessedletter)) {
            
            char [] randomWord = d.toCharArray();   
            char CharGuessedLetter = guessedletter.charAt(0);
            
            
            //gets the index of the guessed letter in the randomword
            builder.append(randomWord);
        
            int index = builder.indexOf(String.valueOf(CharGuessedLetter));
            
            //is supposed to set the correctly guessed letter in the correct index 
            builderDisplay.setCharAt(index, CharGuessedLetter);
                 
            rättord.setText(builderDisplay.toString());
        

        
        }
        
        
              
        field.setText("");
   
    
    }

    
    
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g ) {
    
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (error == 1)
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);

    if (error == 2) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
    }
    
    if (error == 3) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
    }
    
    if (error == 4) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
    }
    
    if (error == 5) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);

    }
    
    if (error == 6) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);

    }
    
    if (error == 7) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);

    }
    
    if (error == 8) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);

    }
    
    if (error == 9) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 200, 310, 240);

    }
    
    if (error == 9) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 200, 310, 240);

    }
    
    if (error == 10) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 200, 310, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 170, 400, 150);

    }
    
    if (error == 11) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 200, 310, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 170, 400, 150);
        g.drawLine(350, 170, 300, 150);
        

        
  }        
  
    if(error > 11) {
        
        g.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 26));
        g.drawString("GAME OVER", 225, 150);
        
    }

}
    


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HangMan");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    JLabel rubrikOrd = new JLabel("rätt gissade ord");
    rubrikOrd.setOpaque(false);
    rubrikOrd.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    rubrikOrd.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);

    JLabel rättord = new JLabel();
    rättord.setOpaque(true);
    rättord.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    rättord.setBounds(10, 35, 100, 20);
    
    
    
    
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    field.setVisible(true);

    JButton b = new JButton("ok");
    b.setBounds(370, 300, 100, 30);
    frame.add(b);
    field.setSize(300, 30);
    field.setLocation(60, 300);
    field.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(field);
    frame.add(rättord);
    frame.add(rubrikOrd);

    frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);

    HangManSO object = new HangManSO(b, field, frame, rättord);
    b.addActionListener(object);
    field.addActionListener(object);
    frame.add(object);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getX() + " " + e.getY());
}


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}


@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

}
```

Comment: can you add the more from the exception stacktrace? there might be the instruction that actually raises the exception

Comment: `builderDisplay` is initiated with empty (length == 0). You can init it with a string whose all space characters which has length == answer.length.

Comment: However, you don't need a string builder. A simple array or array list is enough.

Comment: Another idea to fix your code, before calling `setCharAt`, you can check the length of current `builderDisplay`. If the index is >= `builderDisplay.length`, do append instead of `setCharAt`

Comment: Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,%20char)

Comment: @TuanChau  *A simple array or array list is enough* - 1) if the StringBuilder is empty, you would still have the same issue if you use an Array or ArrrayList  2) You wouldn't use an ArrayList when dealing with individual characters. *builderDisplay is initiated with empty* - which is perfectly fine. In fact the is the norm. You start with an empty StringBuilder and append text as required.

Comment: @camickr ah, I didn't mean Array or ArrayList will fix the problem, just another topic to simplify the code. For _You wouldn't use an ArrayList when dealing with individual characters_, I don't get your point. Why shouldn't we use ArrayList when dealing with individual characters?

Comment: @TuanChau Why would an Array be simpler? The task is to track all the correctly guessed characters. This is simpler with a StringBuilder or StringBuffer because you simply append the newly guessed character. With an Array, you need to track the index so you can add the character at the next position in the Array.

Comment: I see. In general cases, that's right. In the case of @Koshan, the string builder acts like a list or an array (`setCharAt`). To make `setCharAt` work correctly, StringBuilder needs characters from 0 to index. Normally, String builder is used to constructing a string as it optimizes memory usage instead of storing and modifying data.

Comment: And for the optimization purpose, I don't think it's required for this program because it's small. Using `s = s + c` doesn't affect much the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is needlessly complex and that is making it hard for you to see the issue.

Your actual issue starts on this line where you assign the entire correct word `d` to `randomWord`:

```
char [] randomWord = d.toCharArray();
//randomWord now equals `{r,o,m,e}`
```

You then use the entire correct word and append it to your `builder` string:

```
//builder equals a blank string of 4 characters "    "
builder.append(randomWord);
//builder now equals a string with 4 blank characters followed by some "    rome"
System.out.print(builder.toString());
```

So now when you try to get the index of your letter for example if you guessed 'm' it will return a large index:

```
//the builder string now "    rome"
int index = builder.indexOf(String.valueOf(CharGuessedLetter));
//So `m` will be found at the 6th index of "    rome"
System.out.print("index = " + index);
```

So when you use the next line with an index of `6` it will be out of bounds because the `builderDisplay` String is only 4 characters long for the word `rome`:

```
builderDisplay.setCharAt(index, CharGuessedLetter);
```

---

So what can you do to fix this? I won't give you an exact answer, but You should start by thinking about the above code, and where it goes wrong (`append`), and how you can return the correct character index (using the `d` string)

Final hint, the following line would get a correct character index of a character, note how we use the `d` string, not the `builder` string:

```
int index = d.indexOf(String.valueOf(CharGuessedLetter));
```

---

### Edit:

Following on from comments. You also need to fill the string builder with blanks to avoid this issue:

```
//Create the hangman object
HangManSO object = new HangManSO(b, field, frame, rättord);
//Now populate the string builder with empty characters "_" or you could use a space " "
for (int i = 0; i < object.d.length(); i++) {
    object.builderDisplay.append('_');
}
```

Note also that you should check for duplicate characters in your word:

```
//check against every letter of the word to make sure that it gets duplicate characters
for (int i = 0; i < d.length(); i++) {
    if (d.charAt(i) == charGuessedLetter){
        builderDisplay.setCharAt(i, charGuessedLetter);
        System.out.println("Match found");
    }
}
rättord.setText(builderDisplay.toString());
```

Comment: i removed the (d.length) when declaring the Stringbuilders which according to my understanding of what you said, should remove the extra spaces in the code an thus "index" should have the correct int for the placement of the letters and remove the porblem when "randomWord" gets appended to "builder". I also used your method of getting index. However i am continuing to get the same error.

Comment: You will have noticed that the error changed locations, your issue now is that the builderDisplay is initialized with a length of 0, `StringBuilder builderDisplay = new StringBuilder();` but you should use `d.length()` like this `StringBuilder builderDisplay = new StringBuilder(d.length());` to give it the correct legth so that this line works correctly `builderDisplay.setCharAt(index, CharGuessedLetter);`

Comment: i applied that, however as you said the error has changed to: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0.

Comment: @Koshan Awesome to hear. I gave you the wrong info in my last comment, you still need to fill the `builderDisplay` string builder, for example use a loop to set it all to blanks `builderDisplay.setCharAt(i, "_");`. See the edits in my answer above with info, and also a tip on dealing with duplicate characters.